# Remove Observer After Called Once

Tags: android, android-livedata

I have an observer called overrideObserver, and I want to remove it after the toast is showed (Currently, whenever I recall the fragment the toast always showed up). Tried to use removeObserver method, but its not working. Hope any of you can help. Thank You.

```
    private void overrideObserver() {
    overrideViewModel.getBaseResp().observe(requireActivity(), new Observer<BaseResponseModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(BaseResponseModel baseResponseModel) {
            Toast.makeText(context, baseResponseModel.getErrorMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            overrideViewModel.getBaseResp().removeObservers(requireActivity());
        }
    });

}
```

This is what getBaseResp do

```
    public LiveData<BaseResponseModel> getBaseResp() {
    if(baseResp == null) {
        baseResp = new MutableLiveData<>();
    }
    return baseResp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remember the exact instance of the observer that you passed to `observe`:

```
final Observer<BaseResponseModel> observer = Observer<BaseResponseModel>() { ... }
overrideViewModel.getBaseResp().observer(requireActivity(), observer);
```

Then pass that instance to `removeObsever()` when it's time to stop observing:

```
overrideViewModel.getBaseResp().removeObserver(observer);
```

If you only want the current value emitted by the LiveData at a specific point in time, consider instead not using an observer and just accessing the value directly with [getValue()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LiveData#getvalue):

```
overrideViewModel.getBaseResp().getValue()
```

Comment: Thank you, I already edit the question and give the code for getBaseResp(). Gonna try to use this.